# How to beat Mission 17 in Uniwar?

Tags: uniwar

I've been playing this game [Uniwar](http://www.uniwar.com/) for the iPhone. I beat every mission in the campaign, but now I'm on mission 17 and it's impossible. No matter what I do, I just get owned. What is the strategy to beat this mission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since whenever I've played this mission the AI just uses infantry and helicopters I suggest purely using Eclipses and playing to their strengths:

- **Fire from range when possible.**
- Don't be afraid to retreat to avoid close-range combat, especially vs helicopters or on unfavourable ground (Forest / Swamp in this case).
- Conserve your units and pull them back to repair if necessary - keep doing this and you'll end up with an overwhelming numerical advantage.

Also I wouldn't bother trying to capture the enemy's forward base (since the capturing infantry unit will be very vulnerable), just sit a unit on it to prevent spawns.

Remember you don't need to capture bases, occupying all bases without capturing them is enough for victory.

This is based on Mission 17 of the Android version of the game, I'm assuming it's the same as on the iPhone.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU. My mistake was I didn't realize the Eclipses had ranged firing capabilities.

Comment: Now click the red bounty text below the selected answer to award him the bounty.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you had to do that. It says I can't award it for another 11 hours.

Comment: Wow! That was easy. I'd tried throwing tons of titan soldiers, teleporting and swarming, but the damn engineer got me every time even though I tried to kill him as soon as I could. Playing with the eclipse strategy was brilliant. Won in about 8 turns.